# Strategy for getting the best answer(s) to my question about electron-multiplying CCDs?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How often are electron-multiplying CCDs used in telescope focal planes? Will Nancy Grace Roman be the first use in a space telescope?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41035/7982) has been around almost two months but so far there are no answers in sight.

I've given it a bump and the next step is a bounty.

But if I bounty now, when the bounty expires I think the question will be too old to migrate to [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com).

But it's not off-topic here so maybe migration is not an option to begin with.

I wish we had some kind of cross-site visibility option!

**Question:** Strategy for getting the best answer(s) to my question about electron-multiplying CCDs?

1. Bounty?
2. Try to close it and request for migration?
3. Sit tight?
4. Advertise?